# Remove Youtube branding after embedding video in web page?

Tags: html, youtube, embedding, branding

I've a problem with removing Youtube logos after embedding it inside a Web Page.

[I mean this logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocef1.png)

I've already tried with `modestbranding=1` and `showinfo=0` inside my HTML code with no success. I also need that the video have no buttons, bars or something any user can interact with. My actual code is this:

```
   <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="720" height="405" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GTLf1lLRdbU cc_load_policy=1&controls=0&disablekb=1&enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&iv_load_policy=3&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Any solution to my issue? Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 0):

pretty straightforward, this is the code:

```
<iframe allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="405" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GTLf1lLRdbU?enablejsapi=1" width="720" data-gtm-yt-inspected-11424724_51="true" id="59623043"></iframe>
```

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You should be including the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference.